# How would I perform a multi-join query in Bookshelf.js?

Tags: javascript, sql, bookshelf.js

Basically, I have two tables: User and user_connections

`User`:

```
id | email

1 | name@domain.com

2 | name1@domain.com
```

`user_connections`:

```
user_id | key

1 | test1

1 | test2

2 | test3
```

Basically, I need to construct a query that, given the email, pulls a list of connections associated with that email's id.

I already have `User` defined and pointing to the `User` table. How would I get the required results?

---

**EDIT:** Here is the desired result:

If I `GET` with an id of `1`, then I should get the following returned (in JSON):

```
{
  {
    user_id: 1,
    key: test1
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    key: test2
  }
}
```

Comment: show ur desired result

Comment: I have edited the question to show that.

Comment: Use a join and where in the query method

Answer (score 0):

Use [`withRelated`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#examples) in the hash you pass to `fetch`. It identifies an array of column names that you must have defined in your bookshelf model.

```
User
    .forge()
    .where({email: "me@me.com"})
    .fetch({
        withRelated: ["user_connections"] //or however you have defined it in your model defintion
    })
    .then(function(collection) {
        collection.relations// {user_connections: [ {}, {}, ...]}
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
User.query().join('user_connections','User.id','=','user_connections.user_id').where('user.email','=','abc').select('user_connections.key','user_connections.user_id').then(function(collection){
    res.json(collection);
});
```